# how to place a view by percent inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout. It has a number of children. one child is a simple view that draws a vertical line. The problem is I need the line to be at 30% from the left. Does anyone know how I would do that? when I use `dp`, it works in some devices but not in others. Here is the view, thought that's moot.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" />
```

Comment: 30% of what? From the left of what? And what is taking up the remaining 70%? What is this line attached to? Generally speaking, percentage-based layouts are handled by `LinearLayout` or your own custom layout manager, not `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: `layout_weight` is similar to what you are looking for. But its for `LinearLayout`.

Comment: 30% to the right of the edge of the parent. Yes, I am using a LinearLayout now, but I was wondering if RelativeLayout could handle such a percentage based precision.